# Bind (named) DNS Server not properly resolving hostnames

Tags: linux, dns, bind

Having some issues getting my DNS server to work.

As it stands, the DNS server itself cannot get any local dns lookups to work - NXDOMAIN error.

I've connected a client into the network and was able do an nslookup on a hostname, but if I type in the FQDN it gives an NXDOMAIN error.

This server was preconfigured by the configured by the company we had purchased the product though, but sadly we no longer have a contract with them so I can't turn to them for support.

Any ideas what could be causing this? Or where I should start troubleshooting? I'm not much of a networking guy.

Comment: Depends on how it is all configured, and the actual zone file(s) being used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP describes in the self-answer that this was a hiccup, which isn't reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard everyone.

I guess resetting it five times made it work... Lol

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Since this turned out to be a hiccup that isn't reproducible, the question isn't answerable and won't help others.  Consider just deleting the question.